# ETH Validator problem every cca 24h Out of Memory: Killed process 855 (Nethermind.runn)

Tags: ram

I'm new and not so good with Ubuntu linux... :(  please for help in this matter

I'm runing ETH Validator on NUC 12th Gen i7 /32GB / m.2 2TB for validator /ssd 500gb for Windows 11 Pro system.... Windows 11 Pro system and then M$ VM with latest Ubuntu....
by this guide: https://someresat.medium.com/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-ubuntu-lighthouse-773f5d982e03
But the problem is now that cca every 24h my all validators are down and Im geting:
Out of Memory: Killed process 855 (Nethermind.runn) .... Please see attached picture [Picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvyL.jpg)
I have to tell that Im not very good in Ubuntu and linux :(
[VM runing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAjFt.jpg)

Please for help step by step

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu called latest. There are always a few versions that are current. You need an actual version number.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu VM doesn't have enough RAM. The guide you linked to says you need "16GB RAM (32GB is better, and required in some cases).". Your VM has 7901MB which is half (or a quarter) of what's recommended. Give the VM more memory.

Comment: thx man for so fast replay.. I have just up memory to 26000 for VM :) and unchecked Dynamic Memory